# How to access the different objects using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have developed some code for image sliding in which whenever a mouse event occurs I want the `id` of the other `div` except on which the mouse is present.

My code is:

```
$('#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5,#div6').mouseover(function () {
    $('#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5,#div6').css('width', '100px')
    $("." + $(this).data('class')).animate({                   
        'width':"400px",                   
    }, {
        'duration':1500,
        easing:'easeOutBack',
    })
});
```

Comment: Ohhh dear, use class instead 100K of ids.

Comment: Try jquery.not(this): http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Can you provide an [example](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem. It's not very clear in your question. Also, a description of why the code you have doesn't work would be helpful.

Comment: Try $('#'+this.id).animate({yourcode});

Comment: @Dineshkani Why on earth would you do that? `this` is already the element you want, re-selecting it using its `id` property makes no sense.

Comment: numbers are not allowed in ids. O.o but in HTML5 its fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest altering this to use classes rather than ids. It would make your code much neater.

Give every element that you want to have this effect a class of `animated` and try this code instead.

```
$('.animated').mouseover(function () {
  $(this).removeClass('animated');
  $('.animated').css('width', '100px')
  $(this)
    .addClass('animated')
    .animate({                   
      'width':"400px",                   
    }, 1500);
});
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/R6aS7/1/) showing it in action. Although I don't think your code does what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.not` to remove the hovered over div from the set of matched elements.

```
$('#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5,#div6').mouseover(function () {
    $('#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5,#div6').not(this).css('width', '100px')
    $("." + $(this).data('class')).animate({                   
                    'width':"400px",                   
                }, {
                    'duration':1500,
                    easing:'easeOutBack',
                })
    });
```

On a side note, it would be cleaner to use a class selector in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( function() {
$("[id^=div]").mouseover( function() {
  var my = $(this).attr("id");
  var id = new Array;
  $("[id^=div]").each( function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") != my) {
       id.push($(this).attr("id"));
    }
  });
});
});
```

[Working Fiddle or Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/hHgpS/)

You can access each and every property.

I have taken all ids and added all ids to array `id`. You can access it further in your function.